# EF Core 3 1 to 0 relationship problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to define a relationship where a customer can have 0 or 1 addresses. For this relationship, I want the customerId in the Addresses table, but I do not want addressId in the Customer table. Sounds simple? I've looked at samples, but in OnModelCreating some properties such as hasForeignKey or hasOptional are missing, so none of the other samples I looked at work. I am using EF Core version 3.15. No matter what I try, the migration is adding an addressId column to the Customer table. I want to be able to delete all addresses with a sql statement "delete from addresses"

Here are my 2 entities

```
public class AddressEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Customer { get; set; }
}

    public class CustomerEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressEntity Address { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my migration code

```
  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Addresses",
            columns: table => new
            {
                AddressId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Line1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                State = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PostalCode = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Country = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Customer = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Addresses", x => x.AddressId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Customers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                CustomerId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                CustomerName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                CustomerEmail = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                AddressId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customers", x => x.CustomerId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Customers_Addresses_AddressId",
                    column: x => x.AddressId,
                    principalTable: "Addresses",
                    principalColumn: "AddressId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Customers_AddressId",
            table: "Customers",
            column: "AddressId");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, this example can solve your problem.

https://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-table-splitting/

Answer (score 0):

First, write your `AddressEntity` and `CustomerEntity` as follows:

```
public class AddressEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public CustomerEntity Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerEntity
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

   public AddressEntity Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerEntity>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Address)
        .WithOne(a => a.Customer)
        .HasForeignKey<AddressEntity>(a => a.CustomerId);
}
```

Now generate a brand new migration, hope everything will be generated as expected.

Comment: So take out the addressId from the AddressEntity?

Comment: Yes! Because CustomerId will be the both primary key and foreign key for the AddressEntity at the same time.

Comment: Both solutions here look like table splitting, but I used Recep's and it worked beautifully. Looks like there are a more changes in EF Core and need to review that. Thank you

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I want the address to be optional. I thought there was a hasoptional method on the builder

Comment: Address is already optional in my configuration. Copy my code.